Upgrading android gradle to 8.1 version decreased the jacoco code coverage
Now getting many classes with these type of error

Task :app:jacocoTestReport [ant:jacocoReport] Classes in bundle 'app'
do not match with execution data. For report generation the same class
files must be used as at runtime. [ant:jacocoReport] Execution data
for class UserRepository does not match. [ant:jacocoReport] Execution
data for class ViewModel does not match. [ant:jacocoReport] Execution
data for class ProductsRemoteDataSource$getAlternateProducts$1$1 does
not match. [ant:jacocoReport] Execution data for class App does not
match. [ant:jacocoReport] Execution data for class PageViewModel does
not match. [ant:jacocoReport] Execution data for class
ViewModel$createNewOrderInLocalDB$1 does not match.

I have tried firebasePerformanceInstrumentationEnabled=false in gradle properties but not worked. Coverage percentage reduced from 83% to 68%.
